# cannot run ring with lein

Tags: clojure, leiningen, ring

I am trying my first run with ring and lein, and I am facing problems in getting it to run. I have taken this example from the book "Web development with Clojure", chapter 1, and also from https://quickleft.com/blog/your-first-clojure-web-app/ . The code from both these sites give me the same error - Class Not Found.

I have the following project.clj

```
(defproject myfirstwebapp "0.1.1"
   :description "A hello world for a Ring based web app"
   :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
             [ring "1.4.0"]]
   :plugins [[lein-ring "0.9.7"]]
   :dev-dependencies [[lein-ring "0.9.7"]]
   :ring {:handler myfirstwebapp.core/app})
```

And the following core.clj

```
(ns myfirstwebapp.core)
(defn app [req]
  {:status 200
   :headers {"content-Type" "text/html"}
   :body "Hello World!"})
```

And the commands I ran were these:

```
lein new myfirstwebapp
edit project.clj as above
cd myfirstwebapp
lein deps
edit src/myfirstwebapp/core.clj as above
lein ring server
```

And now I am getting errors like:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: leiningen.core.project$reduce_repo_step, compiling:(C:\Users\ROG\form-init7789757414629005682.clj:1:17608)

Is there some mismatch between the versions of different components that I am using? Or something else?

Comment: Initially I suspected it could be a localhost problem on my windows-7. So I turned it on using the suggestion from stackoverflow/24340450. But I still get the class not found error.

Comment: what version of lein are you running?

Comment: lein 2.6.0. Also, I suspected that maybe my java is not compatible, so I moved from java6 to java7u79. Same error.

Comment: the string "Hello World! is missing the closing quote. Is that a paste error?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, there was also a missing quote in the string. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [bug in lein 2.6.0](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/2079). Fixed in 2.6.1

Comment: I have one more question about running a web server from lein: how to stop the process? I did ctrl-c, but then I cant run again unless I reboot the system.

Comment: That is an issue with Windows. Lein by default start 2 JVMs and in Windows ^c just kills the main one, leaving the JVM that runs the server running. I don't have a Windows anymore but try to run `lein trampoline ring server`. That should start just one JVM. If that doesn't work, you will need to find the "java" process in the process admin and manually kill it

Comment: Thanks again. But looks like it automatically finds the next port (moves from 3000 to 3001 and runs again), but it reports an error message, which looks bad.

Comment: Kill first all the "java" processes and try the `lein trampoline ring server` and ^C